# XML Error Completing an AWS SDK MultiPartUpload via V2 SDK

Tags: go, amazon-s3, sdk

I need to upload to an S3 bucket using SignedURLs. I also need to upload multipart files. I have a golang API that vends:

- MultiPart Upload
- Signed URL for each part
- Complete Multipart Upload
- Abort Multipart upload

I am attempting to complete a multipart upload. I have a web endpoint that takes an input from my swift 5 client:

```
type CompletedPart struct {
    Etag string
    PartNumber int
}

type CompleteMultipartUploadRequest struct {
    BucketName string
    Key string
    UploadID string
    MultipartUpload []CompletedPart
}

func putObjectMultipartComplete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    var completeMultipartUploadRequest CompleteMultipartUploadRequest

    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&completeMultipartUploadRequest)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("unable to decode request: %s", err.Error()), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    var completedParts []types.CompletedPart

    for _, part := range completeMultipartUploadRequest.MultipartUpload {

        temp := types.CompletedPart{
            ETag:       aws.String(part.Etag),
            PartNumber: int32(part.PartNumber),
        }

        completedParts = append(completedParts, temp)
    }

    input := &s3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket:              aws.String(completeMultipartUploadRequest.BucketName),
        Key:                 aws.String(completeMultipartUploadRequest.Key),
        UploadId:            aws.String(completeMultipartUploadRequest.UploadID),
        MultipartUpload:     &types.CompletedMultipartUpload {
            Parts: completedParts,
        },
    }

    client := s3Client()

    response, err := client.CompleteMultipartUpload(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("could not complete multipart upload: %s", err.Error()), http.StatusFailedDependency)
        return
    }

    object := CompleteMultipartUploadResponse{
        BucketName: aws.ToString(response.Bucket),
        Key: aws.ToString(response.Key),
        Etag: aws.ToString(response.ETag),
    }

    json, err := json.Marshal(object)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(json)
}
```

I get a 424 back. When I check the error in the server logs I get:

2022/02/01 16:39:29 operation error S3: CompleteMultipartUpload, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: QREDACTE9, HostID: OdE2MREDACThk=, api error MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This code ended up being almost correct. The AWS S3 API mentioned that a part number ID must be a whole number. I had to start counting at 1 and not 0 as sending a part with the number 0 was not valid.